# List Images from azure compute gallery programatically

Tags: c#, .net, azure

I want to get list of image definations from azure compute gallery and in response I also want version vm image version of that vms image definations and want to filter based on name using c#

I have tried this rest api GET [https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/galleries/{galleryName}/images?api-version=2022-03-03](https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/%7BsubscriptionId%7D/resourceGroups/%7BresourceGroupName%7D/providers/Microsoft.Compute/galleries/%7BgalleryName%7D/images?api-version=2022-03-03)
but in its response can't see image version and here filtering mechanism is not there

Answer (score 0):

> I want to get the list of image definitions from azure compute gallery and in response I also want version vm image version of that vms image definations and want to filter based on name using c#

You can use the below sample code to list the image definition and VM image version from the Azure compute gallery using **`Azure.ResourceManager`** and **`Azure.Identity`** package.

In my environment, I have a gallery with two image definitions with versions.

**Code:**

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Azure;
using Azure.Core;
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.ResourceManager;
using Azure.ResourceManager.Compute;
using Azure.ResourceManager.Compute.Models;

TokenCredential cred = new DefaultAzureCredential();
ArmClient client = new ArmClient(cred);
string subscriptionId = "<Subscription-Id>";
string resourceGroupName = "<Your-resource-group>";
string galleryName = "<Your-gallery-name>";
ResourceIdentifier galleryResourceId = GalleryResource.CreateResourceIdentifier(subscriptionId, resourceGroupName, galleryName);
GalleryResource gallery = client.GetGalleryResource(galleryResourceId);
GalleryImageCollection collection = gallery.GetGalleryImages();

await foreach (GalleryImageResource item in collection.GetAllAsync())
{
   
    GalleryImageData resourceData = item.Data;
    // for demo we just print out the id,name,OSState,OSType,Location and versions
    Console.WriteLine($"Image definition Name: {resourceData.Name}");
    Console.WriteLine($"id: {resourceData.Id}");
    Console.WriteLine($"OSState: {resourceData.OSState}");
    Console.WriteLine($"OSType: {resourceData.OSType}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Location: {resourceData.Location}");
    GalleryImageVersionCollection versionCollection = item.GetGalleryImageVersions();
    await foreach (GalleryImageVersionResource version in versionCollection.GetAllAsync())
    {
        GalleryImageVersionData versionData = version.Data;
        Console.WriteLine($"Version: {versionData.Name}");
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Image definition Name: image235
id: /subscriptions/bxxxx/resourceGroups/xxxx/providers/Microsoft.Compute/galleries/gallery1/images/image235
OSState: Generalized
OSType: Windows
Location: eastus
Version: 0.0.2
Image definition Name: image890
id: /subscriptions/xxxx/resourceGroups/xxxxx/providers/Microsoft.Compute/galleries/gallery1/images/image890
OSState: Generalized
OSType: Windows
Location: eastus
Version: 1.1.1
```

[image]

**Reference:**

[Gallery Images - List By Gallery - REST API (Azure Compute) | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/gallery-images/list-by-gallery?view=rest-compute-2022-03-03&tabs=dotnet#list-gallery-images-in-a-gallery.)

Comment: does azure supports pagination while giving list?

Comment: Hi, @PratikshaNatekar What do you mean while giving a list? In the above scenario, all the responses are in `JSON` format.

Comment: How filtering can be done here like if I want filter by name or os type

Comment: Use the if and else condition `resourceData.OSType = windows`  to filter the ostype